# AngularJS ng-click element within directive often unclickable, or clickable outside of element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-directive

I have a simple AngularJS directive that contracts a title if the title exceeds a certain length. When contracted, there is a small chevron icon that is clickable to show the full title. When the full title is displayed, another chevron is shown to contract it. Occasionally the first chevron will only be clickable about 10 pixels above the icon itself, and often the 'contract' icon will be completely unclickable, even though it is displayed.

Directive:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('main')
        .directive('headerTitle', headerTitle);

    function headerTitle() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                brand: '=',
                generic: '=',
                suffix: '='
            },

            template: '{{ brand }} <span id="title-suffix" ng-class="{abbreviated:abbreviate}">{{ generic }} {{ suffix }}</span>' +
                    '<span ng-click="showFullTitle()" ng-show="abbreviate" class="expand-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>' +
                    '<span ng-click="contractTitle()" ng-show="contract" class="contract"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></span>',

            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, fn) {
                scope.generic = (scope.generic) ? '(' + scope.generic + ')' : '';
                scope.suffix = (scope.suffix) ? scope.suffix : '';
                scope.abbreviate = ((scope.brand.length + scope.generic.length + scope.suffix.length) > 35) ? true : false;

                scope.showFullTitle = function() {
                    scope.abbreviate = !scope.abbreviate;
                    scope.contract = true;
                }

                scope.contractTitle = function() {
                    scope.abbreviate = !scope.abbreviate;
                    scope.contract = false;
                }
            }
        };
    }


})();
```

HTML Partial:

```
<div id="drugs-drugdetail" class="container">
    <div id="fullscreenonly" fullscreen="isFullScreen">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading report">
                <div class="h3 report-header">
                    <div id="drugdetail-report-header" class="title pull-left">
                        <header-title brand="Drug.aedrug_name" generic="Drug.aedrug_generic" suffix="TitleSuffix"></header-title>
                        <div class='drug-report-header-container'>
                            <div class='drug-report-data'>
                                <div class='primary-suspect-cases'>
                                <span class="header-label h4" id="drugdetail-cases-label">Primary Suspect Cases:</span>
                                <span class="h4" id="drugdetail-cases-value">{{ Metrics.counts.primary | number }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='data-complete-through'>
                                <div class='drug-report-data'>
                                    <span class="header-label h4" id="drugdetail-date-label">Data Complete Through: <span class="h4" id="drugdetail-date-value"> {{ data_updated }}</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="drug-header-buttons">
                                <div class="header-button-padding">
                                    <button ng-click="goFullScreenViaWatcher()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa aexicon-desktop"></i></button>
                                    <button ng-click="localStorageClearAll()" class="btn btn-primary reset-grid-button">Reset Grids</button>
                                    <span class="dropdown">
                                        <compare-menu categories="overviewData"></compare-menu>
                                    </span>
                       //redacted code for readability...
```

Comment: Possibly, it's because the ng-click is assigned to a span. Try changing those to divs, or give a fixed width to those span elements.

Comment: I tried giving the span elements a fixed width, and also tried using inline divs instead, no luck with either @bamboo_inside

Comment: if you right click the chevron and select inspect element, you should get a shaded area for your span element. does the span shaded area occupy your click area?

Comment: it does @bamboo_inside, although i noticed that the issue only occurs when the icons are on the left 1/4 of the page, leading me to think there is an html element overlaying the chevron icons that is receiving the click. in those instances, when i right click on the chevron and inspect element, the element below the chevron is shaded.

Comment: If something is blocking the click to your chevron, you could try adding this css rule: `.chevron { z-index: 10 }`

Comment: thanks @HankScorpio, unfortunately that didn't work. it seems to be a line-height issue, where the line-height was set to .2 for the . primary-suspect-cases div so that the text fits properly, but the element still overlaps the chevron icon. not sure how to maintain the text placement while fixing the line-height...

Comment: Can you make a plunker to demonstrate the issue?
I just tried out your directive's template to see if there was anything in there causing it. The template works fine on its own and the chevrons are clickable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I discovered that some of the legacy code had modified line-heights which were then overlapping the chevron, making it visible but unclickable. I rewrote the html and css for the header, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that some of the legacy code had modified line-heights which were then overlapping the chevron, making it visible but unclickable. I rewrote the html and css for the header, and now it works fine.